# Unable To send Email in R using function

Tags: r

```
FILEPATH <- "LOCATION OF THE FILE"
EMAIL_ID <- "REQUIRED EMAIL ID"

sendEmail =  function(To=EMAIL_ID, Subject="Email Subject", msgBody="",file=FILE_PATH) {

  require(RDCOMClient)

  OutApp=COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  OutMail=OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  OutMail[["To"]]=To
  OutMail[["Subject"]]=Subject
  OutMail[["Body"]]=msgBody

  if(file!="") OutMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(file)

  OutMail$Send()

}
```

Function was created but the mail was not sent.

While executing this

```
OutMail[["To"]]=To OutMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(file)
```

I am facing following error

> Error in [[<-(*tmp*, "To", value = list(3L)) : Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object In addition: Warning message: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, : there is no package called ‘RDCOMServer’

Comment: Do you have any error message?Also why don't you use library(sendmailR) ?

Comment: OutMail[["To"]]=To
 OutMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(file)    While executing this i am facing following error  Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, "To", value = list(3L)) : 
  Can't attach the RDCOMServer package needed to create a generic COM object
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘RDCOMServer’

Comment: How about the question about not using sendmailR?

Comment: This will help you I hope: http://blog.yhat.com/posts/building-email-reports-with-r.html